# High Availability WordPress setup

Tags: wordpress, performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, high-availability

I'm going to run WordPress site in HA(High Availability) environment at AWS.

I already use HA MySQL - Amazon Avrora.

Right now I have a few question:

1. Should I prefer Session Replication or Sticky sessions or at my Load Balancer or both of them ?
2. User content must be uploaded to CDN and not to WP single node in cluster?

How AWS can help with WordPress HA setup ? For example should I use AWS Beanstalk for this purpose ?

What else should I pay my attention to in order to create HA for WordPress ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions are perhaps a bit broad for StackOverflow, but I am in your situation so I can sympathize.

1. Sticky sessions are not the preferred option because the need to use them would suggest that your application is not stateless.

In other words, you are requiring sticky sessions, that means your application relies on server memory for session management so, once a session is initialized, that user must stay on THAT server for the entire duration of the session. This is OK, but less desirable (compared to if your request didn't care at all which server instance it was running on)  because if your traffic slowed down and Elastic Beanstalk decided to kill off the instance you were on, then on the next request when the load balancer routed you to another instance, your session would be RESET and your user would have to login again.

On the other hand, if your app was written to be completely stateless (by storing the state in a db instance for example), then you would not care which server each request hit because state would not be stored on the server instance. This would allow Beanstalk to freely spin up and down instances without affecting your users in any way.

The benefit to sticky sessions is, if your app is already written with a dependence on server memory, or MUST have it for some reason, it allow your app to run without code changes.

2. Yes, it seems to me like your user-content should not be uploaded to any single node (for mainly the same reasons I mentioned above). If your user-content is stored on the node and that node gets spun down due to low traffic, you will have lost that data.

This is where something like S3 comes in handy. Your application interacts directly with S3 as its storage solution and each instance saves content to your S3 bucket(s). Then, regardless of which node is running, it can just talk to the same S3 bucket and get the data it needs.

Aside from that, all I can recommend is that you experiment, look into load testing, and adjust as needed.